# redux reducer not updating state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to Redux, and reading through the documentation while I try to make a basic to do list.

I can't seem to get my reducer to add an item to the list. The correct action creator is firing, I think there is perhaps something in my `Object.assign` statement that I am not understanding. Below is my `store.js` file.

```
const defaultState = {
    todos:[
  {
    text: 'walk gilbert'
  },
  {
    text: 'cook dinner'
  },
  {
    text: 'clean bathroom'
  }
 ]
}

function todos(state = defaultState) {
  return state;
}

function modifyList(state = defaultState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        todos: [
          ...state.todos,
        {
            text: action.text,
        }
      ]
    })

  default:
    return state;
 }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({todos, modifyList})

const store = createStore(rootReducer, defaultState);

export default store;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the full code? Where are you dispatching the action?
I tried to reproduce the issue but i'm unable. https://codepen.io/olivercs/pen/dWwzpj?editors=0012

Comment: my repo is at https://github.com/AntonEmery/react-redux-todo/tree/todo-list-redux/react-app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you're a bit confused about how `combineReducers` works.

The `combineReducers` utility is intended to both define the fields or "slices" in your state tree object, and also delegate the work of updating those slices to specific functions.  In your case, it looks like you really just want to have a `state.todos` slice, but the way you're calling `combineReducers()` is actually creating `state.todos` and `state.modifyList`.  In addition, when you use `combineReducers`, each slice reducer only ever sees its one piece of the overall state tree.  In other words, inside of the `todos()` reducer, the `state` parameter is *just* the `todos` section.

So, what you want is something more like this:

```
const defaultTodosState = [
    {text : 'walk gilbert'},
    {text : "cook dinner"},
    {text : "clean bathroom"}
];

function todos(state = defaultTodosState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO': {
        return [
          ...state,
          {text: action.text}
        ]
    }
    default:
      return state;
   }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({todos});
```

You might want to read through the sections of the Redux docs that discuss `combineReducers` and reducers in general:  [Introduction - Core Concepts](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/CoreConcepts.html), [Basics - Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html), [API Reference - `combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html), and [Structuring Reducers - Using `combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UsingCombineReducers.html).